# Error in constexpr in building DirectX 12 sample code

Tags: constexpr, directx-12

I want to build DX 12 Sample Code but I got the following error.
[image: Error in DX 12 Build]

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with DirectX 12. It's [DirectXMath 3.09](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/08/02/directxmath-3-09/) in the Windows 10 SDK (14393) which implemented `constexpr` support for some of the data types for Visual Studio 2015--the `constexpr` language feature was not supported by Visual Studio 2013.

**The IntelliSense compiler flags it as a conformance issue, but it has no problem building with the 'real' compiler.**

In any case, I cleaned this up for DirectXMath 3.10 which will be in the next Windows 10 SDK release. You can either ignore it--which as I said is fine because it still builds without any errors or warnings--or you can grab the latest copy of DirectXMath from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath).

If you'd like a more targeted fix, the specific changes to resolve this issue are in this [changelist](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/commit/1fc676109c20cfff60a70dec1f97f828f4887cd7).

> While we are on the subject of DirectXMath and `constexpr`, it turns out there is a bug with the VS 2015 RTM compiler that is fixed in later updates. If you are using VS 2015 Update or VS 2017 as you should, it's a non-issue. But for completeness, there's a workaround that treats VS 2015 RTM as if it were VS 2013 (i.e. it doesn't use `constexpr` unless you are building with VS 2015 Update 1 or later). See this [changelist](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/commit/3906b317a14b8e9889f2fd84d8cf432047bdd7cd).